# Possibility on implementating sending Direct message using Twitter API

Tags: iphone, ios, twitter, ios5

I would like to know how to send Multiple Direct message on Twitter. In my app using twitter api, i am able to send Direct message to one( Using DM Syntax ).

Currently i can see some tools like MultiDM website allows to send multiple Direct messages at a time.
So is that possible from iPhone's twitter api?

Also i wonder how the MultiDM website works as such

Pls let me know

Answer (score 0):

In twitter API there is only 1 method of sending a DM: https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1/post/direct_messages/new

If you need to send multiple DM's - just call this method multiple times (with different recipient)

Comment: Hi, So you mean that we cant send multiple DMs at onece.am i right? pls let me knwo

Answer (score 0):

Yes  you cant send DM to more than one user in a single call of the API.
If you want to send DM to multiple users, just make an array of all users id or screen name and in a loop send direct messages to All through the below API...
https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1/post/direct_messages/new